# C++ lock mutex multiple times from same thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have background download thread that, if download is finished, call user specified callback. User can set same callback for different downloads.

In my callback code, I have this:

```
obj->lock();
obj->doSomething();
obj->unlock();
```

And obj is a global reference to Object.

```
class Object {
    std::mutex lck;

    void lock() { lck.lock(); }

    void unlock() { lck.unlock(); }

    void doSomething() {}

}
```

The above code is undefined behavior if called from the same thread. I have found recursive_mutex, but I am not sure if it is a correct solution.

Comment: Could you give an example usage and what did go wrong?

Comment: this code is fine. could you print the exact code, that is supposed to behave undefined?

Comment: This code is fine as long, as callback is called only once. But If it gets called twice from the same thread, `mtx.lock()` is already locked